# Dynamically change min value in jquery validate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to switch the min: value in jquery validate depending on what value is in a select box. I set minqty = 1; quantitystrerror sets the error message. When the select box changes the input value, the alert shows me that the value for minqty = 25.

However, for me to generate the message error, I have to set $('input.quantity') to 0. The alert tells me minqty = 25. The validation error message says, "Please enter a value greater than or equal to 1". Thus, it's not grabbing my quantitystrerror update, and the new min value is ignored.

```
var minqty = 1;
var quantitystrerror; 
 $('.row select').change(function(){
  minqty = 25;

});
$('input.quantity').change(function(){
        $(".quantity").rules("add", {required: true, digits: true, min: minqty});
        if ($(this).val() < minqty){
            $("#addtocartForm").validate();
        }
        quantitystrerror = "A minimum of "+minqty+" is required";
        alert($(this).val() + " minqty: "+minqty);
});

$("#addtocartForm").validate({
            rules: {
                quantity: {
                    required: true,
                    digits: true,
                    min: minqty
                }
            },
            messages: {
                quantity: quantitystrerror
            }
        });
```

Comment: The docs don't imply that a function is accepted as the value of the min parameter, but have you tried something like `min: function() { return minqty;}`

Comment: `min: function() { return minqty;}` worked :) 

I tried `quantity: function() { return quantitystrerror;}` 
but that didn't change the default error message.

Comment: Ok great. I have added it as an answer - please accept it when you can. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the only way to get the error message to switch was by adding a custom method to jquery validation. I reworked the tutorial here https://chinhplq.wordpress.com/2016/05/18/dynamic-error-message-in-jquery-validation/

Rather than adding rules and messages to $("#addtocartForm").validate(); the new FlagQTY method is assigned to all inputs where the class equals quantity. Thus, I don't need to define the rules, messages, or use .rules() to define the change elsewhere.

In the `addMethod`; the function returns as valid when the input `value >= minqty`. Else, I set the error message via `newPara = "A minimum of "+para+" is required"`. If `minqty == 1` , then the error message becomes `newPara = "Please set a quantity";`

Lastly, in `addClassRules`, I have to bind this method to a input class; `quantity`. Also, I have to call `FlagQTY: function() { return minqty;}` to ensure that the change in minqty's value is carried into the function. Thus, when `minqty` is set to 25 **( via `$('.row select').change(function(){});` )**, the error message output will then be "A minimum of 25 is required".

```
var minqty = 1;
var quantitystrerror; 
 $('.row select').change(function(){
  minqty = 25;
});
 $.validator.addMethod("FlagQTY", function (value, element, para) {

              return (value >= minqty);

            },function(para, element){
                  var newPara = "A minimum of "+para+" is required"; // manipulate your value
                  if (minqty == 1){
                    newPara = "Please set a quantity";
                  } 
                  return $.validator.format("{0}", newPara);
            });
            $.validator.addClassRules({
                quantity: {
                digits: true,
                required: true,
                FlagQTY: function() { return minqty;}
                }
            });
$("#addtocartForm").validate();
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs don't imply that a function is accepted as the value of the min parameter, but have you tried something like

```
min: function() {
    return minqty;
}
```